# Add different numbers in each row in the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, gridview, datatable

hi i have a Gridview that load from the database and i create a column in the Gridview name lblImportanceRatio and i need this column to generate those number in every row 25,20,35,20

this is the Gridview:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xotx.png)

and the column name SymbolicRate i wanna just generate those number  25,20,35,20 in every row i tried to add the generate number in the Grirdview row data bound in for loop but it only give me the last number in the all column i'm Using Asp.net C#

this the Gridview:

```html
    <asp:GridView ID="gvRptBattalion" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="gvRptBattalion_RowDataBound" Visible="false">
                            <Columns>


                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReadinessTypeName" HeaderText="Type" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SymbolicRate" HeaderText="Rate" />

                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="SymbolicRate"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblImportanceRatio" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Total"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BattalionDate" HeaderText="#">
                                    <FooterStyle CssClass="hide_identity" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hide_identity" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hide_identity" />
                                </asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SUnitId" HeaderText="#">
                                    <FooterStyle CssClass="hide_identity" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hide_identity" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hide_identity" />
                                </asp:BoundField>


                                <asp:TemplateField>

                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TotalAll"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFormla" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterStyle CssClass="lbl" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="lbl" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="lbl" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField>

                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TotalALL2"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblG" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterStyle CssClass="lbl" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="lbl" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="lbl" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                         
                            </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: add your code that isn't behaving as it should.

Comment: the Total column and  All total are empty  i will fill them later if the SymbolicRate filled i just need a code that will fill the column in Gridview  with number i add it in code

Comment: add your code behind code for rowdatabound